# Unique responses rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like to determine if a visitor has already submitted a form.

I was thinking of doing a couple of things:

- cookie
- ipaddress
- requiring login (much less desirable since the signup barrier might dissuade visitors)

Is there a ROR gem for this? If so please post a link.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you intending on saving the data?

If you're planning on putting this into a model, great. Then you can create some form of unique value (I'd probably base it on an MD5 of IP address and user agent), store that in a field, and require it to be unique for each submission.

There probably is a gem for this, but it's pretty simple anyway.

If you're not putting it into a model, I think we need more details of what your intentions are.

Comment: I was planning on putting in a model for that reason. I also wanted to use a model so I wouldn't have to write sql. (use the abstraction while its there right? :) )

Comment: Absolutely, use the abstraction while it's there! You can always override the default SQL Rails will use later, if you need to. Hope this helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great opportunity to use HTML5's local storage engine.

You can store up to ~5MB and it's persistent.

YUI has a good wrapper for it.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/